# Create heatmap with variable cell width based on time duration

Tags: python

I am struggling on finding a way to adjust the cells width with seaborn. I am searching for a solution to plot my data with the width of each cells being proportional to a time duration. In the example code, I have 3 cells corresponding to 3 'events' that don't last for the same amount of time (see the duration time in the dataframe data). I want to include the duration time to scale the width of the cell. I attach as well the example code and the data that serves to create the [plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FtiuE.png). Someone can help?

```
import matplotlib
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame({'Date':['2021-01-07', '2021-06-07', '2021-07-21'],
                     'Duration':['5 days 03:00:00', '15 days 02:00:00', '2 days 10:00:00'],
                    'L':[3, 1, 3], 'Pe':[1, 3, 1]})
data.set_index('Date', inplace=True)

data_plot = data[['L', 'Pe']]

cmap=matplotlib.cm.get_cmap('viridis')
color=[cmap(0.25), cmap(0.5), cmap(0.75), cmap(1)]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 3))
ax=sns.heatmap(data_plot.T, cmap=color, cbar_kws={'label': 'Classes', 'ticks':[1, 2, 3, 4]})
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

A cheap solution would be to create arrays with a spacing of a common divisor of your durations and then fill them according to these durations. So if you have a duration of 5, 3 and 2 days with corresponding values a, b and c, you could create the arrays with a 1 day-spacing:

```
array = [a,a,a,a,a,b,b,b,c,c]
```

This will fail spectacularly though if your common divisor is small against the duration.

Comment: I had thought about that but the problem then will be that I will need to rearrange all my tick labels manually that they are not plotted several times and get centered. So I keep that in mind but if there is a 'smarter' way to do it, it would be great!